# I want to read buffer from device that is connected to the port im using windows.h C++

Tags: c++

I'm making frames with the bytes that I read from a controller.

The first 100-200 frames are good, but after that I start to get bad frames. I checked 10000 times that my class' parsing of frames is good. That's why I'm asking if there is maybe a problem with reading from the device.

This is my code:

```cpp
int ConnectDevice::getBytes() {
    DCB dcb;
    BYTE Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile(
            chosePort().c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);
    if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) {
        std::cout.flush();
        system("cls");
        getBytes();
    }

    dcb.BaudRate = 115200;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeout;
    timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 50;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    SetCommTimeouts(&Byte, &timeout);
    if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
        return false;

    while (1) {
        SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); 
        if (_deviceProtocol->IsFrameReady != 1) {
            WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwCommModemStatus, 0);
            if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR)
                ReadFile(hPort, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, NULL);
            else if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_ERR)
                return 0x101;
            _parseFrame->ParseGCSFrame(Byte);
        } else if (_deviceProtocol->IsFrameReady == 1) {
            _deviceProtocol->IsFrameReady = 0;
            _kalmanFilter->displayKalman();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if `CreateFile()` or `ReadFile()` fail. And why are you calling `getBytes()` recursively if `GetCommState()` fails? You will end up in an endless loop doing that. Also, you are calling `SetCommTimeouts()` incorrectly (clearly you are not compiling with [STRICT type checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking) enabled). And you are leaking the opened device `HANDLE`.

Comment: leaking the opened device HANDLE?

Comment: Re: "leaking" - you are not calling `CloseHandle(hPort)` before exiting the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Should I SetCommTimeouts() outside the loop and check if it fails first?

Comment: You are already calling `SetCommTimeouts()` outside the loop. But you are not checking it for failure. And you are not calling it correctly, you are passing it `&Byte` where `hPort` should be. If you had `STRICT` enabled, the compiler would have failed on that mistake.

Comment: @RemyLebeau about this getBytes() calling i just want user to have posibility to back to choice again if the connaction fails (he chose wrong port), better to do it with swich cases?

Comment: @RemyLebeau and about  CloseHandle(hPort); for now its endless loop well only possible way to close the problem is to close the terminal ( i will change it propably) but in this situation calling  CloseHandle(hPort); is pointless?

Comment: using an iterative loop would be more appropriate than a recursive loop. But either way, you need to close `hPort` before trying to open it again.